# How to parse current PHP file after it is loaded?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have a `php` page which receives `POST` attributes.This page is then rendered depending upon these attributes. I want to get the source code of the `php` page after it is fully populated from the received attributes. This page will be a plain `html` code after it has been parsed by the `php` parser. I have referred to `file_get_contents` and `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` but couldn't find any acceptable answer.

What I want is the raw html code after it has been parsed be the `PHP Parser`

**Example**

```
echo "<p>Hi<p>"
```

And the page would return

```
<p>Hi</p>
```

I want this output as above.

Comment: [output buffering](http://us3.php.net//manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) comes to mind, but i don't fully understand the question

Comment: you want the raw php source code (`<?php echo 'foo' ?>`)? or the OUTPUT of that php code (`foo`)?

Comment: htmlspecialchars with output buffering should be sufficient.

Comment: @AugustusFrancis See my answer below

Comment: updated -answer: output buffering  or write the html to a php string, you can still echo it at the end or do anything else you like.

Comment: I have updated my question to meet SO standards. Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PHP's [output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to get the output generated by PHP.

**Example:**

```
<?php

// From here on, keep all output in a buffer
ob_start();

// Output whatever you want
echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "<p>How're you doin' today?</p>";

// Store the contents of the buffer in $output
$output = ob_get_contents();

// Clear the buffer and stop buffering the output
ob_end_clean();

// Show the output we caught using the buffer
var_dump($output);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
string(52) "<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>How're you doin' today?</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the options below using the POST method and supplying your POST parameters:

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

Curl may be a good option for this also...

Answer (score 1):

HTML Special Chars with Output Buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "<h1>Heading</h1><br>\n";
echo "<p>Randomsampletext</p>";
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

You can use `htmlspecialchars($output);` to output the raw HTML that is generated in the php script, or you can do anything with the $output variable, like echo it, etc.

Will display the raw HTML:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Randomsampletext</p>
```

Comment: Keeping the \n in there will show up as a new line in the source code as well.